# Regex to exclude all chars except letters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm a real regex n00b so I ask your help:
I need a regex witch match only letters and numbers and exclude punctations, non ascii characters and spaces.

"ilikestackoverflow2012" would be a valid string.

"***f### you °§è***" not valid.

"***hello world***" not valid

"***hello-world***" and "***hello_world***" not valid

and so on.

I need it to make a possibly complex business name url friendly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds to me like for your application you don't just want a regex to tell you if the input matches or not, but you want to filter the input and get something out that is more friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
var test = new[] {"ilikestack", "hello world", "hello-world", "###"};

foreach (var s in test)
   Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", s, regex.IsMatch(s));
```

**EDIT:** If you want something like @Andre_Miller said, you should use the same regex with Regex.Replace();

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "")
```

OR

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
regex.Replace("input-string-@#$@#");
```

Comment: This post helped me more than I asked. This is exactly what I have to do.

Answer (score 2):

To validate a string you can use the following regular expression with `Regex.IsMatch`:

```
"^[0-9A-Za-z]+$"
```

Explanation:

- `^` is a start of string [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).
- `[...]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).
- `+` means one or more.
- `$` is an end of string anchor.

---

> I need it to make a possibly complex business name url friendly

Then you want to replace the characters that don't match. Use `Regex.Replace` with the following regular expression:

```
"[^0-9A-Za-z]+"
```

Explanation:

- `[^...]` is a negated character class.

Code:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9A-Za-z]+" , "");
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/ZSDbb)

---

Note that different business names could give the same resulting string. For example, businesses whose names contain only Chinese characters will all give the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$
```

Matches one or more alphanumeric characters with no spaces or non-alpha characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below regex.

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Comment: Thanks! I missed that. Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this.

```
string s = "......"
var isValid = s.All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit);
```

-

> I need it to make a possibly complex business name url friendly

You can also use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`

```
var urlFriendlyString = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(yourString);
```

Comment: He could be using a RegularExpressionValidator

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

[www.regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com) is a GREAT resource.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `[:alnum:]`? It's a posix standard. So your whole regex would be: `^[:alnum:]+$`.

The [wikipedia article for regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) includes lots of examples and details.